# with java downloaded file is too small

Tags: java, android

i use this code snippet to download some mp3-files:

```
File target = /*...*/;
InputStream in = new URL(link).openStream();
Files.copy(in, target.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

it usually works fine, but now i have a series of files, that are way too small and don't work. for example: https://kritisches-denken-podcast.de/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/KDP-Episode-17-Selbsterhaltungstherapie.mp3 should be about 46MB(when i download it via browser) but is only 315 Bytes when i download it with the code above on my android.

Comment: Check those 315 bytes; it's probably HTML, with either an error, or more likely a redirect which openStream isn't following. Also, your snippet isn't closing resources, but that's a separate issue.

Comment: u r right, it says that it has been moved and gives me the new adress. is there a simple way to let my code download the correct path in such cases or do i have to check, if the target contains such text?

Answer (score 0):

The URL has a redirect built into it. Usually such redirects, especially for URLs targeted at non-browsers (Which an mp3 URL clearly is), are served up as an HTTP 301 'Moved Permanently' (and sometimes 302 'Moved Temporarily'), with the right URL sent along in the `Location` header. The text you see (the 315 bytes you download) is merely 'fallback' HTML that also state the content has moved. There is no need to parse this, fortunately.

The HTTP 'browser' of URL's openStream code is very basic and does not follow redirects. You need an API that does. URLConnection (also from the core libs) can do it, but it does not follow redirects if the redirect switches from http to https or vice versa, so you might not wanna do that. Just in case you do:

```
File target = /*...*/;
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(link).openConnection();
con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
try (InputStream in = con.getInputStream()) {
    Files.copy(in, target.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
}
```

If the above is no good (presumably due to HTTP/HTTPS redirect issue) I suggest picking up a real HTTP client, which the standard API does not provide. I suggest [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/).